# Spring-Boot 2 fails in Gradle 4 build because of missing StyledTextOutputFactory, but why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build

I'm trying to set up an OAuth2 authorization server based a [tutorial](http://stytex.de/blog/2016/02/01/spring-cloud-security-with-oauth2/) by David Steiman. Currently, I want to check if [that solution](https://github.com/xetys/spring-cloud-oauth2-example) still works with most current versions of the included libraries. Working solely on the `OAuth2ResourceServer`sub-project I change the corresponding entries in `build.gradle` so that it now looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot' 

jar {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.2.1.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.0.9.RELEASE')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

Actually, at first, I tried Spring Boot version `1.5.10.RELEASE` which works perfectly fine. But I need to use Spring 5 and therefore Spring Boot 2. But with `2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`, the spring boot Gradle plugin tells me that I have to use at least Gradle 4.0, so I can not use the Gradle wrapper that comes with the sample project. I had version `4.2.1` installed on my system but also tried with `4.5.1`. What I get when using Gradle 4 is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\stefa\Projekte\spring-cloud-oauth2-example\OAuth2ResourceServer\build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':OAuth2ResourceServer'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin']
> Could not create task of type 'DependencyManagementReportTask'.
```

The root cause of the corresponding stack trace is:

```
...
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.UnknownServiceException: No service of type StyledTextOutputFactory available in ProjectScopeServices.
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:324)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.convertParameters(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:119)
    ... 144 more
```

Which led me (among other places) [there](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/87). The versions I am using should not have the problem anymore as far as I understand. But what completely confuses me is that I am actually using Spring Boot `2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and Gradle `4.5.1` in my "real" project and it works perfectly well there.

I created an [example-project](https://github.com/szauner/spring-boot-jersey-example) which uses Spring-Boot 2 and Grade 4 and works perfectly well. What am I missing?